# What does it mean to be open in a set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I've been proposed the following theorem:

**Show that if $D\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ then $S \subset D$ is open in $D$ if and only if it is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$.**

I know the definition of being an open set, but what is the definition of being open **in** another set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saying $S \subseteq D$ is open in $D$ means that $S$ open in the subspace topology on $D$. That is, $S = U \cap D$ for some open set $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$.

What this statement is saying is that, if $D$ is itself open in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $S$ being open in $D$ is equivalent to $S$ being open in $\mathbb{R}^n$, since $S = D \cap S$ (so take $U = D$ in the above definition).

However, if $D$ is not open then this may not be the case... for example, $[0,\frac{1}{2})$ is open in $[0,1]$, since $[0,\frac{1}{2}) = (-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}) \cap [0,1]$, but it is not open in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, now I get it!

Answer (score 1):

You can define open sets in $D$ in this way.

$U$ is open in $D$ $\iff U=V\cap D$ where $V$ is an open set in $X$  ( the topological space)